# Cannot access windows folder (dual boot laptop)

Tags: dual-boot, mount, ntfs

Somehow I cannot access my windows folder. It worked fine for the last couple of months. This is the first time this happened.

[image]

Comment: Look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Please [open a separate question](/questions/ask) about the screen flickering issue. It's harder to answer multiple unrelated questions at the same time than to answer a single question or multiple closely related questions. I took the liberty to remove the that part from your post.

Comment: Thank you for the links! I disabled the fast boot option in my windows OS. :)

Answer (score 0):

Start the windows OS again and cleanly shutdown or restart the laptop from there. Then check from the ubuntu. Your problem should be fixed.

The problem could be, that **fast boot enabled** is enabled in Windows. So Windows dos not unmount the partitions when shutdown process but on restart it will.

Comment: Also you must turn off hibernation completely in Windows 10: start a Powershell as Administrator and enter `powercfg -hibernate off`